# Zooming createjs canvas prevents button click

Tags: css, createjs

When the canvas that contains a createjs is zoomed using a `zoom` style (e.g. `zoom: 0.5`) buttons on the canvas have a different click target that is either on only one side of the button or no target at all.

```js
var stage, label;

function init() {
  stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
  stage.name = "stage";

  var background = new createjs.Shape();
  background.name = "background";
  background.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRoundRect(0, 0, 150, 60, 10);

  label = new createjs.Text("foo", "bold 24px Arial", "#FFFFFF");
  label.name = "label";
  label.textAlign = "center";
  label.textBaseline = "middle";
  label.x = 150/2;
  label.y = 60/2;

  var button = new createjs.Container();
  button.name = "button";
  button.x = 75;
  button.y = 40;
  button.addChild(background, label);

  stage.addChild(button);

  // listeners
  var targets = [stage,button,label,background];
  for (var i=0; i<targets.length; i++) {
    var target = targets[i];
    target.on("click", toggleText, null, false, null, false);
  }

  stage.update();
}

function toggleText(evt) {
  label.text = (label.text == 'foo') ? 'bar' : 'foo';
  stage.update();
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#demoCanvas{
  background: tan;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;  
  transform: scale(0.2);   // Firefox = This does not cause problem with button clicking
  zoom: 0.2;               // Other browsers = This causes a problem with button clicking in Chrome
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
      <canvas id="demoCanvas"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that this will not fail in the SO snippet so I have also made this [available as a Pen](https://codepen.io/mpoo/pen/oNYEZPJ).

This behaviour presents itself in Chrome but not in Firefox (which recognises the `transform: scale()` style instead).

If the canvas needs to be scaled in the DOM how can this be done in Chrome without causing buttons to fail?

Answer (score 1):

The zoom css style is considered non-standard so for Chrome and other Browsers you can use transform : scale() as well.  I can confirm that zoom does break CreateJS - if you wanted to, you could add an issue to their EaselJS GitHub - not sure if it is worth fixing when transform : scale() can be used. Cheers.

CSS ZOOM: "Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

Comment: Thanks Dan. I ended up coming to the same conclusion and am using `transform: scale()` for all browsers.
There is a 5 year old issue on their Github at https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/649 which I commented on 9 days ago.